# Windows 2012 SSTP The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, windows-server-2012, certificate-authority, crl

In order to get rid of "Error 0×80092013: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline" you have to install base/delta CRLs on the client you want to connect to the VPN server...

However, it would seem that I have to frequently install the CRLs from my Certificate Authority server on my clients (every couple of days, not just once) - a task which is rather cumbersome. Is there a way to automate the CRL download/addstore or actually fix this issue (without disabling CRL check)?

Comment: The certificates should contain a CRL Distribution Point that is online and accessible from the clients. Such as `http://crl.yourdomain.com/yourcert.crl`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you don't put the CRLs on the client, you put them in the CDP that is defined *in* the certificate.

I suppose it's possible that you wrote a CDP into the cert that was file://c:/local/path/whoops, in which case that's not really what you wanted. You want a publicly-accessible URL, so read up on the docs for your CA and re-issue the certs with a better CDP.